# hashResult variable is not storing the correct values

Tags: c, windows, hash

I have a program that generates a hash key from a file.
For example the result of the program is `"hash of file c:\Users\Jax\Desktop\files\file.txt is: 4db5a10d2ea73e3f76"`.

And I have a variable that has the expected hash for this file.txt:

```
char hashExpected   = "4db5a10d2ea73e3f76";
```

And in a specifc part of the code I'm verifying if the result hash of the program is equal to the hash stored in the `hashExpected` variable. I have this like below. I have the `hashResult` variable storing the result hash so then I can compare. But it's not working properly because it always shows `Hash is different` even when it's equal. It seems that the `hashResult` variable is not storing the correct values.

```
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c",
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
            hashResult[i] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
            hashResult[i] += rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
        }
        if (verify(hashResult, hashExpected))
        {
            printf("Hash is the same\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Hash is different\n");
        }
```

Full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

bool verify(char array1[], char array2[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array1[i] && array2[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
DWORD main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    PCSTR filename = "c:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\file.txt";
    char hashActual[]   = "4db5a10d2ea73e3f76";
    char hashExpected[] = "4db5a10d2ea73e3f76";
    char hashWrong[]    = "0a0a0a0a0a0a0a";
    char hashResult[] = "";
    hFile = CreateFile(filename,
                       GENERIC_READ,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                       NULL);


    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", filename,
               dwStatus);
        return dwStatus;
    }


    // Get handle to the crypto provider
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             PROV_RSA_FULL,
                             CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }


    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return dwStatus;
    }


    while (bResult = ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE,
                              &cbRead, NULL))
    {
        if (0 == cbRead)
        {
            break;
        }


        if (!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return dwStatus;
        }
    }


    if (!bResult)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("ReadFile failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }


    cbHash = MD5LEN;


    if (CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        DWORD i;

        printf("MD5 hash of file %s is: ", filename);
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c",
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
            hashResult[i] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
            hashResult[i] += rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];


        }
        if (verify(hashResult, hashExpected))
        {
            printf("Hash is the same\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Hash is different\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
    }


    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);


    return dwStatus;
}
```

Comment: Buffer overflow: Your `hashResult` array only has one element. You access it with `hashResult[i] = ...`, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char hashExpected[] = "4db5a10d2ea73e3f76";
```

Above MD5 value is wrong. MD5 values are 16 bytes long. But that's just for the bytes. We cannot print bytes on the screen, so often times we convert bytes to hexadecimal values. For example, if we have `unsinged char bytes[3] = {0x01,0x01,0xFF}`, we convert bytes to hexadecimal string, it becomes `"0102FF"`.

Note that the string representation is twice longer plus a nul-terminator. Example of MD5 hash is:

```
"C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B"
```

The buffer size for the string should be `33` (16 x 2 + 1)

To find the correct `hashExpected`, search for *"Online MD5 calculator"*. You can use a website like http://onlinemd5.com/ to calculate the MD5 of file.

Or use a file whose content is `1`. `MD5("1")` is `"C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B"`, use that as expected hash value.

```
char hashResult[] = "";
```

Above line is a programming error, as mentioned in comments by @melpomene

```
hashResult[i] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
hashResult[i] += rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
```

Above code is wrong, you want this instead:

```
char hashResult[MD5LEN * 2 + 1] = "";
...
hashResult[i * 2] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
hashResult[i * 2 + 1] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
```

Also there is a problem with the function `verify` because it is comparing the wrong MD5 in byte representation with the wrong MD5 in string representation.

You can use `strcmp` or `_stricmp` to compare MD5 values in string representation. Or use `memcmp(data1, data2, 16)` to compare bytes directly.

Full example:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

int main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    PCSTR filename = "c:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\file.txt";

    //assuming content of file.txt is '1'
    char hashExpected[] = "C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B"; 

    char hashResult[MD5LEN * 2 + 1] = "";
    hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", filename, dwStatus);
        return (int)dwStatus;
    }

    // Get handle to the crypto provider
    if(!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return (int)dwStatus;
    }

    if(!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return (int)dwStatus;
    }

    while(ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL))
    {
        if(0 == cbRead)
            break;

        if(!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return (int)dwStatus;
        }
    }

    cbHash = MD5LEN;

    if(CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        DWORD i;

        printf("MD5 expected, versus MD5 of file %s is:\n", filename);
        printf("%s\n", hashExpected);
        for(i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c",
                rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
            hashResult[i * 2] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
            hashResult[i * 2 + 1] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
        }
        printf("\n");

        if(_strcmpi(hashResult, hashExpected) == 0)
            printf("Hash is the same\n");
        else
            printf("Hash is different\n");
    }
    else
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
    }

    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return (int)dwStatus;
}
```

Comment: Thank you really for your detailed explanation. Now I understand the issue. Now I was trying expriment your solution but its showing a strange error " error: '::main' must return 'int'". Do you have idea why can be?

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! Thanks again for the detailed explanation.